# Ruby sources generated by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to see sources generated by interpreter for Ruby on Rails?

For instance ERB templating engine parses html with ERB blocks.Then parsed output should be rendered somehow, etc. I believe there should be explicit code (generated by iterpretered) to accomplish this. Just want to see how all this stuff works internally.

Here is an analogue from ASP.NET world: HttpRuntime.CodegenDir, which gets physical path to the directory where ASP.NET stores temporary files (generated sources, compiled assemblies, and so on) for the current application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each request to the server causes the ERB template to be interpreted.

Because Ruby is a dynamic language there is no pre-compilation step and therefore no source of the generated output.

ERB can be modified between HTTP requests and that modified template will be available on the next HTTP request.

Rails does cache the generated output but it would be difficult to find it in the cache directory.